# Best way to get long value from object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, bltoolkit

I would like to know the best way to obtain long from returned BIGINT value from MSSQL server via BLToolkit
which will be better?

```
long.Parse(db.Parameter("@rowCount").Value.ToString());
```

or

```
System.Convert.ToInt64(db.Parameter("@rowCount").Value);
```

?

Answer (score 2):

i would cast like this:

```
long lngVal = System.Convert.ToLong(db.Parameter("@rowCount").Value);
```

In this case I would not cast the object to String before, because there is no reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think below is a good way to retrieve data as you wanted:

```
long longValue = 0;
if(db.Parameter("@rowCount").Value!=null)
{
    long.TryParse(db.Parameter("@rowCount").Value.ToString(), out longValue);
    //longValue: contains the actual long data
}
```

Since exception is very costly and according to above code exception is handled. So it will provide better approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The second form is better as it *stays* a long. Converting to/from a string might potentially lose precision due to binary<->decimal conversions.

Answer (score 0):

use `(long)db.Parameter("@rowCount").Value`
or `(long?)db.Parameter("@rowCount").Value` if your value could be null.

Comment: If the Value could be null, you shouldn't use this prefix-cast. Prefer a as-cast if the value could be null, because of performance.

Answer (score 0):

one way is type cast it long from string

```
((long)(db.Parameter("@rowCount").Value.ToString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int nRowCnt = db.GetOrdinals("@rowCount");
db.GetInt64(nRowCnt);
```